# python function to find difference between 2 datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I want to write a function that can get an input like "2022-09-12 13:18:36,270" and then calculate difference between input and now.

```
def compute_target_time(date_time):
        reach_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(hours=int(date_time))
    return reach_time
```

but it doesn't work. can you help me?

Comment: Are you expecting `int("2022-09-12 13:18:36,270")` to work…?!

Comment: how it should be?

Comment: I think you might do some extra work to format your datetime.utcnow(), and compare it to your input afterwards

Comment: can you say more?

Answer (score 1):

```
def compute_target_time(date_time):
    reach_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')
    return reach_time
```